# Trying to see if all classes got this specific grade

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying pull students who received a F or W for all their classes. Each class is in different orders. I am wondering if there is a way to get only people who have received those paticular grades. I am also trying to get people who didn't even receive a grade for those specific terms as well.

This is my current script; however, it's only pulling if one class out of a student got a F or W.

```
`select distinct spriden_id, spriden_first_name, spriden_last_name

  from spriden

 inner join rrrareq
    on rrrareq_pidm = spriden_pidm
   and rrrareq_treq_code = 'UEH359'
   and rrrareq_trst_code = 'E'
   and rrrareq_aidy_code = 2324

  left join shrtckg
    on shrtckg_pidm = spriden_pidm
  where exists (select 1
          from shrtckg
         where (shrtckg_grde_code_final = 'F' or
                shrtckg_grde_code_final = 'W'))
   and (shrtckg_term_code = '202208' or shrtckg_term_code = '202302' or
       shrtckg_term_code = '202305')
   and spriden_change_ind is null

 /*left join shrtckg b
 on b.shrtckg_pidm = spriden_pidm
 and b.shrtckg_grde_code_final is null
and (b.shrtckg_term_code = '202208' or b.shrtckg_term_code = '202302' or
    b.shrtckg_term_code = '202305')*/`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT spriden_id, spriden_first_name, spriden_last_name
FROM spriden
INNER JOIN rrrareq ON rrrareq_pidm = spriden_pidm
    AND rrrareq_treq_code = 'UEH359'
    AND rrrareq_trst_code = 'E'
    AND rrrareq_aidy_code = 2324
LEFT JOIN shrtckg ON shrtckg_pidm = spriden_pidm
    AND shrtckg_term_code IN ('202208', '202302', '202305')
    AND (shrtckg_grde_code_final = 'F' OR shrtckg_grde_code_final = 'W')
WHERE spriden_change_ind IS NULL
GROUP BY spriden_id, spriden_first_name, spriden_last_name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT shrtckg_term_code) = 3
   OR COUNT(DISTINCT shrtckg_term_code) = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the improved query, it looks like it is giving me what I want. I do have a question what do lines 12-13 do? I know what the clauses do but my brain does not understand how it is being used. Still very new to writing SQL. Thanks again!

Comment: To ensure that a student received either all 'F' or 'W' grades for the specified terms or no grade at all, we use GROUP BY and HAVING clauses. The HAVING condition checks the count of distinct shrtckg_term_code values. If it's equal to 3 (meaning the student has a grade for each specified term), or if it's equal to 0 (meaning the student has no grade for any specified term), then the student is included in the result.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to want to count when there are no grades that are not either `F` or `W` (i.e. they are either all `F` or `W` or there are no grades):

```sql
SELECT s.spriden_id,
       s.spriden_first_name,
       s.spriden_last_name
FROM   spriden s
       INNER JOIN rrrareq r
       on r.rrrareq_pidm = s.spriden_pidm
WHERE  r.rrrareq_treq_code = 'UEH359'
AND    r.rrrareq_trst_code = 'E'
AND    r.rrrareq_aidy_code = 2324
AND    s.spriden_change_ind is null
AND    EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
         FROM   shrtckg c
         WHERE  c.shrtckg_pidm = s.spriden_pidm
         AND    c.shrtckg_term_code IN ('202208', '202302', '202305')
         HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN c.shrtckg_grde_code_final NOT IN ('F', 'W') THEN 1 END) = 0
       )
```

*Note: you do not need to prefix every column with the name of the containing table. It just means that you have to type more and doesn't bring any particular benefits that you could not achieve by using either the table identifier directly or an alias defined in the query.*

Comment: Hi, thank you for the improved script. I ran it and it looks like it is giving me what I want. I do have a couple of questions if you do not mind. I am still a beginner when it comes to writing sql only one year in. I am confused about the meaning of line 16. could explain it to me? thank you.